# chain indexing of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, view

According to the following article, `view` shares memory, so the original data must be changed regardless of the warning message.

> `df["b":"d"]["z"] = 0`
>
> This mirrors the behavior that you’ve seen in the article so far. df["b":"d"] returns a view and allows you to modify the original data. That’s why the assignment df["b":"d"]["z"] = 0 succeeds. Notice that in this case you get a SettingWithCopyWarning regardless of the successful change to df.
>
> https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/#impact-of-data-types-on-views-copies-and-the-settingwithcopywarning

If range slicing(`iloc[0:2]`) is applied to dataframe with all integer columns, the view is returned. The view needs to modify `C` column, but it does not work in the example below..

```py
data = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
index = ["1/1", "1/2", "1/3"]
columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

df = DataFrame( data, index, columns)
df.iloc[0:2]['C'] = 1000
print(df)
```

```
     A  B  C
1/1  0  1  2
1/2  3  4  5
1/3  6  7  8
```

I am not sure what is different from the explanation in the article.

Comment: This is a known issue, and lots of edge cases [No SettingWithCopyWarning for chained indexing when .loc or .iloc is first indexer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18752)

Answer (score 0):

with loop, can change it.

```
data = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
index = ["1/1", "1/2", "1/3"]
columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
for i in range(len(index)):
    df.iloc[i]["C"] = 1000
print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant to the question. For your information, it is better to use `df.loc[:, 'C'] = 1000` than chain indexing.